# Matplotlib with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, matplotlib

I am having trouble importing matplotlib into google app engine. I have googled around and found some solutions but none of them seem to work for me. In my app.yaml file I have

```
libraries:
- name: matplotlib
  version: latest  
- name: numpy
  version: latest
```

In my python file I will import numpy I can have

```
numpy.arange(10)
```

The problem is when I try to import matplotlib

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

I get this error when visiting the page

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8080/. 
It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

I remove the matplotlib import, refresh, and everything works again. I have seen app engine webpages use matplotlib such as http://gae-matplotlib-demo.appspot.com that import matplotlib so I know it is possible.

How can I use matplotlib in Google App Engine?

Comment: There's some discussion about matplotlib on app engine [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578393-gae-matplotlib-demo/). Maybe you're hitting development SDK issue?

Comment: Do you have matplotlib installed on your computer?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459320/using-matplotlib-in-gae

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Matplotlib does not currently work in the GAE Dev Appserver, as explained in [Matplotlib notes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#matplotlib) on the libraries page. It should work if you deploy it to the production server using appcfg. I realise this is not ideal for development, though. We will update that page when the development server supports Matplotlib.

As @mjibson pointed out, Dima Tisnek has [worked out a way](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578393-gae-matplotlib-demo/) of getting it working in the dev appserver, but it involves a bit of hacking, and we don't officially support this approach. (For the record, I was able to get it working with this approach.)

Matt Giuca

Google

Comment: Thank you. I was a bit confused on why I couldn't even import the module. Hopefully GAE gets updated soon so we can use matplotlib on the dev server.